# Append Query Doesn't Append Missing Items

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have 2 tables. Table 1 has data from the bank account. Table 2 aggregates data from multiple other tables; to keep things simple, we will just have 2 tables. I need to append the data from table 1 into table 2.

I have a field in table2, "SrceFk". The concept is that when a record from Table1 appends, it will fill the table2.SrceFk with the table1 primary key and the table name. So record 302 will look like "BANK/302" after it appends. This way, when I run the append query, I can avoid duplicates.

The query is not working. I deleted the record from table2, but when I run the query, it just says "0 records appended". Even though the foreign key is not present.

I am new to SQL, Access, and programming in general. I understand basic concepts. I have googled this issue and looked on stackOverflow, but no luck.

This is my full statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Main ( SrceFK, InvoDate, Descrip, AMT, Ac1, Ac2 )
SELECT Bank.ID &"/"& "BANK", Bank.TransDate, Bank.Descrip, Bank.TtlAmt, Bank.Ac1, Bank.Ac2
FROM Bank
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Main
        WHERE Main.SrceFK = Bank.ID &"/"& "BANK"
     );
```

I expect the query to add records that aren't present in the table, as needed.

Comment: Works just fine for me. Post some sample data.

Comment: As you are new to Databases, you should get familiar with Database-Normalization first, because wrong decisions there are hard to correct later! E.g. avoid storing a concated value like`Bank.ID & "/"& "BANK"`, instead save them into seperate fields, one for the`Bank.ID`number  and one for the type ("Bank" this time, but that should be replaced by a key from a new table where you store the different SrceTypes.),

Comment: What do you consider 'duplicate' - all 6 fields? Edit question to show sample source data and desired result.

Comment: Ignore the `INSERT INTO` piece for now.  Does the `SELECT` piece return any rows?

Comment: @NickFleetwood . . . Your delete probably wasn't successful.

Comment: @HansUp nope, nothing

Comment: @ComputerVersteher not opposed. I actually built the fields that way, and I was going to play it both ways.

Comment: If you want become wise through experience, save the concated values, but don't complain later :) If you provide sample data ( [formated text](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) we can debug the query! Did you reduce it to smaller parts (Select From Bank part and Select From Main part).